# How to make CTRL+L lock screen in ubuntu 14.04 without gnome-settings-daemon

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, lock-screen

I use IceWM without gnome-settings-daemon. How to make CTRL+L combination to work as in native ubuntu environment?

Comment: This question would be better if you indicated *how* Ctrl+L works in the "native Ubuntu environment", since that would allow anyone with knowledge of IceWM to answer. As it currently stands, only people familiar with *both* Ubuntu *and* IceWM would likely be able to offer an answer, severely limiting your possible respondent base.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
key "Ctrl+l" xlock
```

to ~/.icewm/keys.  Restart IceWM.  Of course, you'll need xlock installed for this to work.